# Listing events in wordpress

Tags: civievent, wordpress

So I would like to use the CiviCRM events in wordpress, in a page listing multiple events, using the shortcodes. If I create a page in wordpress with the following:

```
[civicrm component="event" id="584" action="info" mode="live"]
```

It is fine, it will display the single event. However, if i was to add another event into the page, it doesn't display. Ideally I would like to use this shortcode inside of Advanced Custom Fields. The reason for doing this is we need to display only certain events for a page which members are logged in to view.

```
<?php 

if( have_rows('events') ): ?>

    <ul>                 
        <?php while( have_rows('events') ): the_row(); ?>
            <li><?php var_dump(get_sub_field('event')); ?></li>         
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The vardump above literally returns null. Any ideas how I can do this. I am aware of the civievent wiget but that lists all events that are upcoming.

Just to clarify this is for civicrm 4.5.4. Cheers.

Comment: Which version of Civi are you using?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify civicrm version - that's a crucial detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was an issue prior to 4.6--you couldn't have more than one instance of CiviCRM content on a screen.  Christian Wach did a lot of work to change this for 4.6--that's why he was asking what version you're on.

In short, if you're not on 4.6, upgrade.  If you are, you may have found a bug.

Comment: Awesome, that's just what I wanted to hear, thanks! :)

Comment: I couldn't becase it was marked as on hold. Will do so now =]

Answer (score 1):

If you use the WP plugin Ajax event calendar you can put your events into categories, and use a shortcode to list all events of a given category on a page or post..