# CiviEvent widget: change date format?

Tags: civievent

I am trying to work with the [CiviEvent widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civievent-widget) but several things baffle me. First, the date format is all wrong and I don't see a way to change that? The date is correct on the event page, but not in CiviEvent.

**What I have:** Date format is set to `%E.%b%Y %H:%M`
**What I get:** `Okt. 22, 2023 5:15 pm`
**What I expect:** `22.Okt.2023 17:15`

How can I get the widget to output the correct date format?

**Edit:** I see that the plugin was [last updated 5 years ago](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civievent-widget) and [this bug has already been reported 4½ years ago](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-date-time-format/), so I guess the code is abandoned and there will be no solution to this problem until someone publishes a fork that fixes this. Dang!

**Edit 2:** I contacted the devs and they responded that "It's definitely patch-welcome, so not strictly abandoned, but we aren't proactively doing work on it." I am not a sufficiently skilled developer to fix this, so it will have to be that way.

Answer (score 0):

Try: Administer > Localisation > Date Formats

Comment: The definition of **"What I have"** is exactly that. It is already set correctly, but you can see that the CiviEvent widget disregards this and just does its own thing.

Comment: I see that the plugin was [last updated 5 years ago](https://wordpress.org/plugins/civievent-widget) and [this bug has already been reported 4½ years ago](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-date-time-format/), so I guess the code is abandoned. Dang!

Comment: Right. My bad, i didn't read the question well enough before I answered, and therefore i didn't realise this involved a 3rd party extension.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could suggest alternative solutions! (see also [this related question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45695/how-to-show-courses-events-as-a-table-listing-in-wordpress))

Comment: Have you read up about SearchKit? We don't do a lot of WP work. You may want to ask at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/search-improvements

Comment: Oh i see that is the answer in that 'related question'

Answer (score 0):

At lines 188-200 in civievent-widget.php

You can change the original parameters to  %d.%B.%Y and %H:%M

```
// Get date and time formats.
    $params = array( 'name' => 'date_format' );
    $values = array();
    CRM_Core_DAO::commonRetrieve( 'CRM_Core_DAO_PreferencesDate', $params, $values );
    $this->_dateFormat = CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'date_format', $values, '%A %d %B %Y' );
    $params = array( 'name' => 'time_format' );
    $values = array();
    CRM_Core_DAO::commonRetrieve( 'CRM_Core_DAO_PreferencesDate', $params, $values );
    $this->_timeFormat = CRM_Utils_Array::value( 'time_format', $values, '%H:%M' );
}
```