# How to make a FormBuilder form visible to visitors? (not logged-in users)

Tags: wordpress, formbuilder

In [this other question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/45695/15929), I learned how to create a shortcode for a FormBuilder form that shows a SearchKit search result of events. I then discovered that **WordPress does not render the shortcode form unless you are logged in.**

**What I have:**

- My test setup is newest WP 6.3.2 and newest CiviCRM 5.66.0.
- CiviEvent: several events.
- SearchKit: a search that gives me the results I want.
  The result presents no actions, no sorting, just a static table listing.
- Form Builder: a form to hold the results from the search.
  The "permissions" field is intentionally blank, but that's not enough to make the form content public.
- WordPress: a page that contains the shortcode with my search.
  **This works correctly when I am logged in, but is simply not rendered for public visitors.**

**What I want:**

- The form content should be visible to public visitors (not-logged-in users).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an FB form that's submitted by anonymous users.  The 'Permission' on the form's settings page is set to 'Generic - Allow all users (including anonymous)' and on each contact page 'Security' is set to 'Form based'.  This is a Drupal 7 system but should work for all.  Credit to Coleman of course who helped with this..

Comment: Yes and you also need to edit the Search Display and disable permission checks.

Comment: _Fantastic!_ Thank you both so much. The Form Builder permission 'Generic - Allow all users (including anonymous)' also exists on the WordPress platform, and that gave me the table in the public web page - but only the header, no data rows. I then found that the SearchKit 'Result' section also has permissions that I set to 'bypass permissions' = and now I see it exactly as I wanted! <3

Comment: ...almost what I wanted. I discover that the event/registration links in the output is broken because, when included in the page `mysite.com/courses/`, then unfortunately `/courses/` is inserted into the actual link. The link given in SearchKit is `civicrm/event/info/?reset=1&id=10` becomes `https://mysite.com/courses/?civiwp=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fevent%2Fregister&reset=1&id=10`. I will put this into a new topic!